# Flexible Methods To Add and Update Records

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework (and C# for that matter) so not sure how EF all exactly works.  I have it working in my code and have watched videos, but I want to do more.  I'm trying to nail down the syntax and organization of my code, but I'm having trouble and would really like some help with it.  I'll give you the background.

Each day I parse a text file and sometimes I will add a record to my MySQL database or sometimes update a record.  There are 3 tables in the database, but may eventually grow larger.  What I first did, just to get it working was create a Records class and created separate methods that would run depending on what the format of that certain section in the text file was.  So for example, "A 3284712039875817230987123", would be an Address layout and the program reads the first letter, decides on the parser method to run in the Records object and runs the method.  There are about 6 different parser methods, where each parse a different "layout" in the text file.  Also in the Records class they each have some helper methods.

Ok, so that's the background.  Now for obvious reasons you can see that this is messy.  What I would like to do is essentially create an abstract parent class Records, and have its children be each layout in the text file.  So have an Address layout, Data layout, which would contain their individual parser but also inherit some methods that I use over and over like adding/updating records and other ones.

**The question that I have is: How do I write the formal parameters in a method so that I can pass the EntitySet and the Entity without defining the exact EntitySet and Entity type?**

For example something like this:

```
public void AddRecord(EntitySet entitySet, Entity entity)
{
    context.entitySet.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm confused on how I should construct the method.  Hope this makes sense.  Let me know if I need to clarify something.

thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method would be add those methods to your `DbContext`. You don't even have to supply the EntitySet, just an entity. **This code doesn't take care of the parsing part.**

```
public void AddRecord<T>(params T[] items) where T : class
{
    var set = Set<T>();
    foreach (var item in items)
        set.Add(item);
}
```

A generic remove is as easy.

```
public void RemoveRecord<T>(params T[] items) where T : class
{
    var set = Set<T>();
    foreach(var item in items)
        set.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: This is looking good, however when I add the code to my project, it says, "Cannot resolve symbol 'Entity'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'Set'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'Add'". So I can't seem to call this method...I have all the correct references I thought.

Comment: oh yeah I got the parsing part all taken care of.  I'm just trying to organize my code a little better.  Thanks tho!

Comment: Those methods are to be added to your DbContext. I've change the `Entity` to `class`

Comment: I'm almost there.  I'm not totally understanding the parameter type that the AddRecord method uses or the type of my entity sets.  If I simply want to create a wrapper for AddRecord called WrapperAddRecord what are the parameter types that I would used?  I tried WrapperAddRecord(EntityObject entity){context.AddRecord<EntityObject>(entity);}, however when I call WrapperAddRecord(addressEntity) it says that "Argument type is not assignable to parameter type."

Comment: Using the Generic `AddRecord<T>(...)` method. All classes can be pass to it. With your Wrapper, you are forcing the <T> to be a `EntityObject`. Is your `addressEntity` Type inheriting from `EntityObject`?

Comment: Ah, I got it now about the Generic `AddRecord<T>` No it's not inheriting `EntityObject`, so would I simply do `Wrapper(Object entity)`?  Would it be proper to use `Object` as the parameter type since I don't know which entity I will be passing it?

Comment: If you want a Wrapper you could. But why not use the generic method by itself?